# How to record when a control is triggered in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I'm trying to figure out how to tell when controls have been triggered `Manipulate` (in `Animate`, actually, but I take it `Manipulate` is the heart of the matter). After no luck from Search on -- `Manipulate` control --
 through 407 questions, and scores re `CurrentValue`, I'm hoping this isn't a redundant question.

Given code such as

```
Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1, Animator, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
    "FasterSlowerButtons", "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton"}
  }
 ]
```

I'd like to know how to tell a) when, for instance, the `"PlayPauseButton"` has been hit, and, b) what's its current value). Same for `"StepLeftButton"`, `"StepRightButton"`, and both `"FasterSlowerButtons`".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way, but you can monitor values of options which are affected by those elements. Here is a small example:

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{
   animationRunning = True,
   animationRate = Automatic
   },
  Grid[{
    {Animator[Dynamic[x], {0, 1}, 
      AnimationRunning -> Dynamic@animationRunning, 
      AnimationRate -> Dynamic@animationRate], SpanFromLeft},
    {},
    {"AnimationRunning:", Dynamic@animationRunning},
    {"AnimationRate:", Dynamic@animationRate}
    }
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

Another option is to create many `Animators` with a single `AppearanceElements` option in each to compose one `Animator` where you can wrap each element with `EventHandler`:

```
Panel @ DynamicModule[
  {lastAction, x}

, animatorElement[element_String, running_: False] := EventHandler[
    Animator[Dynamic[x], {0, 1}
    , AppearanceElements -> {element}
    , AnimationRunning -> running
    ]
  , { "MouseEntered" :> (lastAction = "entered " <> element)
    , "MouseExited" :> (lastAction = "exited " <> element)
    , "MouseClicked" :> (lastAction = "clicked" <> element)
    }
  , PassEventsDown -> True
  ]

; Column[{
    animatorElement["ProgressSlider", True]
  , Row[animatorElement /@ {"PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons",        "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton"
    }]
  , Dynamic[{x, lastAction}]
  }]
]
```

Comment: Very cool !  Thanks, Kuba."Dynamic@animationRunning" solves my "Is it running?" question perfectly.That teaches me something about how parameter specifications work, too. I'm aware that the specified AnimationRate and the actual one may not be identical if there's heavy lifting being done inside Manipulate. So, I'll be sure to verify the frame rate in my application with a smoothed-average function, or something of that sort. Your second bit is quite elegant. You're teaching us to think outside the box in solving a problem.